# Site moves around inside browser on mobile devices showing browser background?

Tags: css, responsive-design

When i scroll right or left or up and down on mobile devices, my site seems to detach from the browser, here's a link http://www.lunacarpentry.com  Not sure why?

Comment: I do not know what you mean. Your site looks fine in the iOS simulator.

Comment: you have an Unclosed element `ul` in line 94, just FYI. plus your `br` are badly closed. instead `</br>`should be `<br />`